# Dropping two masses on a spring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, energy-conservation, spring

I had a doubt regarding this after going through a problem.

A thin plate $A$ of mass $m$ is affixed on the upper end of a spring, lower end of which is affixed to the ground. In equilibrium, the spring is compressed by an amount $x$. Another thin plate $B$ of mass $2m$ dropped from a height $3x$ above plate $A$ hits plate $A$, moves downwards together with plate $A$ and after reaching a lowest position, both plates rebound upwards. What maximum height above the initial position of the plate $A$ will $B$ rise?

My main concern is regarding the speeds of A and B after the spring reached its lowest point(when they rebound up). Could someone help me with this?

Comment: can you please provide a picture of the whole scenario

Comment: It is a little late now, but this question is homework. It should show some effort to work it out, and ask about a specific concept. We should not just do people's homework for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer to the heavily edited question.

---

Firstly calculate the velocity of the mass $B$ just prior to impact on $A$, from conservation:
$$2mg\times 3x=\frac12 2m v_0^2$$
$$v_0=\sqrt{6xg}$$

The collision is inelastic but without external forces, so conservation of momentum applies. An 'instant' after the collision $A+B$ travel at $v_1$:
$$2m\sqrt{6xg}=2mv_1+mv_1$$
$$v_1=\frac23\sqrt{6xg}$$
Now calculate the kinetic energy $K$ of both masses an instant after impact:
$$K=\frac12 3mv_1^2=\frac12 3m(6xg)$$
$$K=9mxg$$
Absent of friction, $K$ is now converted to spring-mass potential energy:
$$\Delta K=W$$
$$9mxg=\frac12 k\Delta x^2$$
where $\Delta x$ is the 'extra' compression of the spring.
$$\Delta x=\sqrt\frac{{2m\times 9xg}}{k}=3\sqrt\frac{{2mxg}}{k}$$

> What maximum height above the initial position of the plate $A$ will $B$
> rise?

Here the OP toils under a misconcption.

At this lowest point the masses have spent all their kinetic energy and have no velocity. All $K$ has been converted into spring-mass potential energy.

Due to the restorative force of the spring this spring-mass potential energy will again be converted to potential (gravity) energy:
$$9mxg=3m\Delta hg$$
So:

$$\Delta h=3x$$

which is of course our original $3x$. Both masses at that point have zero velocity, regardless of whether they are connected or sticky or not.

Comment: Okay, I see. The last part of the answer was very informative, thank you.

Comment: Thank you and thanks for the upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the velocity at impact of $M$ is $v_0$ (which can be calculated from the drop height but that's trivial).

The collision is inelastic but without external forces, so *conservation of momentum applies*. An 'instant' after the collision $M+m$ travel at $v_1$:

$$Mv_0=Mv_1+mv_1=(M+m)v_1$$
$$v_1=\frac{M}{M+m}v_0$$
Now calculate the kinetic energy $K$ of $M+m$:
$$K=\frac12 (M+m)v_1^2$$
$$K=\frac12(M+m)\Big(\frac{M}{M+m}v_0\Big)^2$$
$$K=\frac12\frac{M^2}{M+m}v_0^2$$
This $K$ is converted to potential energy (compression of the spring):
$$K=W=\frac12 k\Delta y^2$$

where $\Delta y$ is the displacement.
$$\frac12\frac{M^2}{M+m}v_0^2=\frac12 k\Delta y^2$$
$$\Delta y=\sqrt{\frac{1}{k(M+m)}}Mv_0$$
Due conservation of energy, $M+m$ will then bounce back to the initial pre-collision $y$ position and enter into a simple harmonic oscillator motion.

> My main concern is regarding the speeds of m and M after the spring
> reached its lowest point.

At the lowest point, all kinetic energy of $M+m$ has been converted to spring potential energy, so the velocity of $M+m$ is $0$.

Comment: You really need to edit your question. I cannot answer issues that aren't included in the question. Good questions beget good answers! Poor questions get downvotes.

Comment: I quoted the problem's wording.